# How to update a single patch from withing a patchset?

Tags: git, open-source, patch, u-boot

I would like to know how to update a patch that is part of patchset and have been already submitted to open-source project?

The tutorials online mention using --amend, but the patch to be fixed is not the last one, instead it's number 2 of 5.

Also, I would like to make sure... Should I submit the whole patchset again or just the fixed one?

- Additional info: the patchset is for U-Boot, created with cover letter & numbered as following:
  git format-patch -o /home/sam/patchset --cover-letter -n --thread=shallow 0b9c250^..fd3c12d

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The precise details might vary slightly depending on the recipients' preferences.  As a general rule, if you need to revise a patch-set, you submit a *new* patch-set, "[v2] ..." (version 2), "v3", and so on.  It's also nice to provide, in the "00/NN" entry, a (cumulative) description of the update.  You can also include explanatory text between the cut-line sections within individual patches:

```
Subject: [PATCH v5 07/11] foo/blah: frobulate the mizzenbeast
...

... descriptive text about the patch extracted from a commit message ...

Signed-off-by: A U Thor <thor@example.com>
---
We can sneak in a bit more information here.  This will not get
added to the commit.

  dir/sub/some.ext                 |  3 ++
  ...
diff --git ...
```

Since such patch-sets are actually just email messages, you *could* just stop using Git at all here.  However, that's doing things the hard way (at least in my opinion).

Since the new patch-set is a new set of email messages, and you might want to keep your existing work, the way to deal with this problem *in Git itself* is to make a new branch.

Suppose the above is a series of patches in your `mizzenbeast` branch.  The way I would handle this is to rename that branch `mizzenbeast-v1` and create a new branch `mizzenbeast-v2`.  You can then `git cherry-pick` each individual commit, one at a time, until you reach the one(s) that need change(s).  At this point you can `git cherry-pick -n` the commit that needs some changes.

You now have, in your index and work-tree, everything staged and ready to commit, but not actually committed.  Now you can make whatever changes you like, `git add` them, and `git commit` the result.

You are now ready to resume cherry-picking any unchanged commits, resolving any conflicts that occur because of the one you did change.  When you are done, your `mizzenbeast-v2` branch contains the new series of commits, ready to `git format-patch` as `[PATCH v2 nn/howmany]` and send to the mailing list for review.

(Note that you will still need to manually massage the text of the formatted patches, to insert the `v2` and any extra information.)

#### Making this easier to do for yourself

There is a somewhat faster and easier way to cherry pick everything and modify it: make your new branch (`mizzenbeast-v2`) pointing to the tip commit of the renamed (`mizzenbeast-v1`) branch, so that both branches are identical.  Then run `git rebase -i <hash or identifier of where to start>`.  This brings up your editor on a series of `pick` commands, that tell Git to do the same cherry-picks you would have done manually.  Change one or more to `edit`, write out the file, and exit the editor.  Git will now being the cherry-picking process, much as above.  However, when it reaches the `edit` one, it will cherry-pick the commit—this time *without* `-n`—but then stop.

Now you can make changes and use `git commit --amend` to replace the current (anonymous) mizzenbeast-v2-in-progress branch tip commit.  This is similar to what you did when using `git cherry-pick -n`, except that you're shoving aside the current commit instead of just adding a new one.

Once that is done, you can run `git rebase --continue` to tell Git to continue with the saved cherry-picking instructions.  If all goes well, it will finish them all and move the `mizzenbeast-v2` branch label to the tip of the new branch.  If something goes wrong (a conflict due to the amended commit in the middle of this process), you will have to fix that up, `git add`, and `git rebase --continue` yet again.

(I recommend waiting to use this "easier" process until *after* you have done it the "hard way", manually cherry-picking each commit, at least once or twice.  The reason is that while this automates that work, it's hard to tell what's happening.  If something goes wrong—and things *will* go wrong—it's very helpful to have a clear idea of what Git was doing, and what you need to do now to fix it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer is helpful. However, It is still not clear in which step can I edit the changes in code (like I usually do using git commit -a)?

Because, replacing the "pick" with "edit" changes the commit message only.

Comment: Don't use the `rebase -i` version until you have mastered the `cherry-pick` version, where you use `git cherry-pick -n`. Then, as an intermediate step, try replacing the `git cherry-pick -n` + work + `git add ...; git commit` sequence with `git cherry-pick` + work + `git add ...; git commit --amend`. Then you will be ready for the `git rebase -i` and `edit` command.